# Rails 4 - how to use a helper method in an index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, helper

I'm getting stuck in trying to use a helper method in my index view.

In my index, I have this view:

```
<% policy_scope(Article).sort_by(&:created_at).in_groups_of(2) do |group| %>

  <% group.compact.each do |article| %>
     <h4><%= link_to article.title, article  %></h4>
     <small><%= state_notice(article) %></small><br>
     <small><%= truncate(article.body, :ommission => "...", :length => 250) %></small>
     <%= link_to 'READ MORE', article_path(article), :class=>"portfolio-item-view" %>
```

The line that is:<%= text_for_state(article) %>
 has a helper method in my articles helper as:

```
 module ArticlesHelper

    def state_notice(article)
      if current_user = article.user
           article.text_for_state(current_state) 
        elsif article.to_be_reviewed and current_user.has_role?(:org_approver)
           article.text_for_state(current_state) 
        else
            'test'
        end  
    end     

        def text_for_state(current_state)
      case current_state
      when 'draft'
        'Private draft'
      when 'review'
        'Under pre-publication review'
      when 'reject'
        'This article has not been approved for publication'

      when 'approve'
        'This article has been approved for publication'

      when 'publish'
        'Published'

      when 'remove'
        'Removed from publication'
      end
    end

end
```

the method 'to_be_reviewed' is defined in my articles policy (I use pundit).

I expect the index view to evaluate whether the user should get text for one of the 3 cases set out in the helper. Instead, I get an error message that says:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_state' for #<#<Class:0x007fba81f217a8>:0x007fba8651f390>
Did you mean?  current_user
```

.

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From where does `article` come? Shouldn't your helper be:

```
module ArticlesHelper
  def text_for_state(article)
    if current_user = article.user
      article.current_state
    elsif article.to_be_reviewed and current_user.has_role?(:org_approver)
      article.current_state
    else
      'test'
    end  
  end     
end
```

Comment: Hi Sam. I tried, that but I get the same outcome (no error, but just a blank field where the text is supposed to be).  I thought maybe passing (article) i the index view would be sufficient to identify which article i want to use the helper with.

Comment: Could your article's current_state be blank? What would happen if you replaced <%= text_for_state(article) %> with <%= article.current_state %>? Still blank?

Comment: Hi Sam - it shows the current state when I make that change. The state can't be blank, because state is initialised with a new article (with state = draft)

Answer (score 0):

Try Following.

```
def state_notice(article)
  if current_user = article.user
    article.text_for_state(article.current_state)
  elsif article.to_be_reviewed and current_user.has_role?(:org_approver)
    article.text_for_state(article.current_state)
  else
    'test'
  end
end
```