# Rails 4 - how can I use a helper method in an index view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I previously asked this related question, but did not find any help [Rails 4 - how to use a helper method in an index view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517467/rails-4-how-to-use-a-helper-method-in-an-index-view)

Im having the same problem in this context. There must be something stopping me from using helper methods in my index action.

I have an index view and a show view. The helper works fine in the show view.

In my index view I have:

```
<% @eois.sort_by(&:created_at).each do |eoi| %>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-5 portfolioitem Scienza">
    <div class="portfolio-item text-center">
      <h4><%= link_to eoi.user.full_name %></h4>
      <span>Interested<%= display_interest(eoi) %></span>
      <%= link_to 'VIEW DETAILS', project_eoi_path(@project, eoi), :class=> "portfolio-item-view" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In my show view, I have:

```
<td><%= @eoi.user.full_name %></td>
<td><%= @eoi.user.profile.organisation.try(:title) %></td>  
<td>Interested<%= display_interest(@eoi) %></td>
<td><%= @eoi.created_at.try(:strftime, '%e %B %Y') %></td>
```

In my helper file, I have:

```
def display_interest(eoi)
  if interested_in_contributing
    'in contributing resources to this project team'
  elsif interested_in_participating
    'in participating in this project'
  elsif interested_in_partnering
     'in partnering with this project team'
  elsif interested_in_granting
     'in assessing this project for a grant'
  elsif interested_in_investing
     # elsif eoi.invest || @invest
    'in investing in the outcomes of this project'
  else
     nil
  end
end

# Depending on the type of interest, then figure out which questions need to be asked.

# If the interest is in participation - there is no need to ask questions relating to asset requests
# TODO - need a better way to check the js on participant_intrest to feed through this same channel
def interested_in_participating
  @eoi.participate || @participate
end

# If the interest is in contributing assets or partnering, need to check which assets are relevant to the interest
def interested_in_contributing
  @eoi.contribute || @contribute
end
```

How come I can't use the helper file from the index view?

Controller:

```
def index
  @eois = Project.by_user_id(current_user.id).find_by(id: params[:project_id]).try(:eois) || Eoi.none
  policy_scope(@eois)
end

def show
  @eoi = Eoi.find(params[:id])
  authorize @eoi
end
```

Comment: "There must be something stopping me from using helper methods in my index action" -- Thats strange whats the error you r getting ??

Comment: undefined method `contribute' for nil:NilClass

Comment: You should be passing arguments to your helpers, not attempting to rely on instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def display_interest(eoi)
  if interested_in_contributing eoi
    'in contributing resources to this project team'
  .
  .


def interested_in_contributing eoi
  eoi.contribute || @contribute
end
```

Comment: in your controller how do you get the @eoi instace in show and index actions ??

Comment: hmmm... remove all the "@eoi" from your helpers "interested_in_<whatever>" and pass it as a parameter to them.

Comment: @RoaringStones I believe removing the instance variables from the private functions is key to solving the problem. Why not make it a suggested answer?

Comment: @RoaringStones - I tried this, but then I get the error wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)and also, it messes up the form to create a new eoi

Answer (score 0):

The error says `undefined method contribute on nil class` and this method is being called on `@eoi` check if you have defined the `@eoi` instance variable on your index action. It should look something like:

```
def index
  @eoi = 'some value'
end
```

It probably is defined on your `show` action but not your `index` action. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the variable `eoi` as argument to `interested_in_participating` and `interested_in_contributing` methods. This is because for index action, the instance variable is `@eois`, not `@eoi`. Here is the code snippet.

```
def interested_in_participating(eoi)
  eoi.participate || @participate
end

# If the interest is in contributing assets or partnering, need to check which assets are relevant to the interest
def interested_in_contributing(eoi)
  eoi.contribute || @contribute
end

# Add parameter while calling the methods
def display_interest(eoi)
  if interested_in_contributing(eoi)
    'in contributing resources to this project team'
  elsif interested_in_participating(eoi)
    'in participating in this project'
  elsif interested_in_partnering
    'in partnering with this project team'
  elsif interested_in_granting
    'in assessing this project for a grant'
  elsif interested_in_investing
  # elsif eoi.invest || @invest
    'in investing in the outcomes of this project'
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

And same goes for the rest of methods if they are using `@eoi` instance.

Comment: I tried this, but then I get an error when I try to render the index which says: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

Comment: It also then gives an error when I try to use the form (which also uses that helper method.

Comment: You must provide a parameter when you are calling a method which accepts non-optional parameter. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Hi @Andolasoft - i tried this, but it doesnt work. It also messes up the form and show views, which were working previously.